# Plotting multiple datasets in single graph

Tags: excel, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I have many datasets taken from multiple excel files that I would like to plot on the same graph each with a different color.
I have created 4 spreadsheets with random data for testing.
The first column defines the measurement, the code should select one of this containing 5 rows of data (X, Y), and add them to a dataframe. The results should be 1 dataset for every file to be plot all together on the same graph and having each plot of a different color.

[Spreadsheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yplW0.png)

I have been using modified pieces of codes taken on here from people which were trying to do the same thing.  The problem is that I cannot color each plot differently because the program counts them as one, because due to the `pd.concat()` it merge these into 1 line. Do you know how I could overcome this?

Other questions asking to plot multiple datasets in single graph are almost all about a small number of dataset, while in my case I have like 50, thus cannot create a subplot for each one of them, unless there is a way to do this automatically

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import os
from os import path
import sys
import openpyxl 

# create a list of all excel files in the directory
xlsx_files=glob.glob(r'C:\Users\exx762\Desktop\*.xlsx')
files=[]
n=len(xlsx_files)
index=0

# select chunk of data needed from each file and add to dataframe
for file in xlsx_files:
    index+=1
    files.append(pd.read_excel(file))
    df_files=pd.concat(files)
    ph_loops=df_files[df_files['Measurement']==2]
    x = ph_loops['X']
    y = ph_loops['Y']

# plot elements in the dataframe
    ax=plt.subplot()
    colors=plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, n))
    ax.set_prop_cycle('color', list(colors))
    ax.plot(x, y, marker='.', c=colors[index-1], linewidth=0.5, markersize=2)
    print(colors[index-1])
    ax.tick_params(axis='y', color='k')
    ax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize=12, weight='bold')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize=12, weight='bold')
    ax.set_title(file+'\n')
    ax.tick_params(width=2)
    plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

[> Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QVQQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an id field (I used `name` below) to the dataframes as you concatenate them, then you can plot in a loop. Example:

```
# Create example dataframes
dfs = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])
    df.insert(0, 'name', i)
    dfs.append(df)

result = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

# Plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for name, group in result.groupby('name'):
    group.plot(x='x', y='y', ax=ax, label=name)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @a11! I had to play around with my original code a few times, but it finally works! Wish you all the best. Thank you again.